# Change text in div onClick of item in list

Tags: javascript, html, list, onclick

This should be pretty simple. Basically when an item in a list is clicked that text is inserted/replaced into a target div. 'replaceWith' is probably not the thing to use because it deletes the original data.
Also how do you add the class of 'selected' to the text in the target div.

Anyway here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/BM8Cb/

HTML

```
<div class="selected" id="here">
   <li>All</li>
</div> 
<hr>
<ul>
  <li>All</li>
  <li>Category 1</li>
  <li>Category 2</li>
  <li>Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {list-style:none;padding:0; margin:0;}
li {cursor:pointer;}
li:hover {color:red;}
.selected {color:red;}
```

JS

```
$("li").click(function() {
  $("#here").replaceWith(this);
```

});

Thank you for any help

Comment: Try [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: A LI element can't be a child of a DIV ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BM8Cb/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$("li.item").click(function() {
    $("#here").html($(this).html());
});
```

If all you need is the text.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to:

```
$("li.item").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).clone();
    item.attr("class","selected");
    $(".selected").append(item)    
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7JST/2/

This will also add the selected class to your item

Answer (score 0):

using replaceWith will replace the DOM node so it's no longer there the next time you try.  You need to use append

```
$("#here").append(this);
```

and By using 'this' you are copy everything include the event handler.  if you want just the text you can do something like

```
$("#here").append(this.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Appending it will add the text on each time, not replace it